# How to install MySQL workbench?

Tags: 11.10, mysql

Installing MySQL workbench on 10.04 or 10.10 is not a problem, as the deb packages are available on MySQL's website.  But there is no 11.04 deb package available.

So, how do I install MySQL workbench on 11.04 and keep it updated automatically when updates become available to ubuntu via `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Select "Ubuntu" from MySQL Workbench [downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) page

You will have a choice of:

```
Ubuntu Linux ver. 10.10 (x86, 64-bit), DEB
(mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1010-amd64.deb)

Ubuntu Linux ver. 10.10 (x86, 32-bit), DEB      
(mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1010-i386.deb)
```

and 2 slightly older versions:

```
Ubuntu Linux ver. 10.04 (x86, 64-bit), DEB
(mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1004-amd64.deb)

Ubuntu Linux ver. 10.04 (x86, 32-bit), DEB  
(mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1004-i386.deb)
```

As you can see there are only 10.04 versions but you can download the `.deb` you need and when it is done downloading Ubuntu Software Center will open up with this screen:

[image: im1]

and the rest is just normal Ubuntu.
I needed it myself (`mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1010-i386.deb`) so I can confirm it works.

Comment: I can second the fact that the `5.2.33b-1ubu1010` install works on 11.04

Comment: I was trying to install the 10.10 version, it would download, and automatically opened up the ubuntu software center.  I clicked install and the ubuntu software center just froze.  I tried the process twice, and got the same results each time.   I will give the 10.04 version a try tomorrow.

Comment: @oshirowanen I had the same issue as you with the software centre freezing - I clicked the 'intall in progress icon' and saw the message 'waiting for synaptic to exit' - sure enough I had synaptic open, and when I closed it everything ran through ok

Comment: The official .deb didn't work for me, instead, the `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench` works well.

Comment: @Dorian you do realise this was a valid answer for 11.04 and the current workbench was added after the answer?

Comment: @Rinzwind You could edit your answer.

Comment: @dorian no, since it then would -not- be an answer to the question (and the person who downvoted should learn when to downvote).

Comment: @Rinzwind It is: Look at other answers, the correct answer is to use apt-get. And please re-read the question. I downvoted because this answer is wrong, users should install mysql-workbench with apt-get and not with this buggy, not up-to-date, proprietary .deb. The thing is: people actually read your answer NOW and the guy who ask don't, so the answer should be up-to-date.

Comment: @dorian no. AT THAT TIME it was NOT possible using apt-get. Please stop using comments on a topic well over a year old.

Comment: @Rinzwind You don't understand that people read it now… I don't want to lose my time with that and it's not really important, just save a bit of time to a bunch of people (your advice would be to repost the question to have a better answer? … did you hear about duplicates?)

Answer (score 71):

Run this command in Terminal  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Comment: Thanks, running an apt-get is almost always preferable + quicker than opening any web browser (in Linux) for me

Comment: Before running the command, it is recommendable update the packages list: `sudo apt-get update` and after that run: `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench`

Comment: For UBUNTU 16, see http://askubuntu.com/a/58207/439867

Answer (score 22):

Finally I found the easiest and direct way of installing MySQL Workbench on my 12.04 LTS.

(1) Simply install Synaptic package manager (from Ubuntu software center).

(2) Find MySQL Workbench under Database category (see the screen shot).

[image]

**EDIT:**
As of August 2012, MySQL has released MySQL Workbench for Ubuntu 12.04, [available here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads)

Answer (score 4):

The cause for me was a broken MWB dependency on libzip.so.1 in Ubuntu 12.04 release.

Synaptic (Ubuntu software manager) saved me with these Ubuntu upgrade growing pains:

```
libzip1:

Package libzip1 has no available version, but exists in the database.
This typically means that the package was mentioned in a dependency 
  and never uploaded, has been obsoleted or is not available with the 
  contents of sources.list
```

Here's a [link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libz/libzip/) to the required oneiric libzip package

Comment: The libzip package link not working... Please show *how to*, all commands  before `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench`

Comment: Libzip1 was deleted, see http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/libzip1   ... See http://askubuntu.com/a/58207/439867 as how-to that works fine.

Answer (score 2):

For the Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10 follow the instructions on [this link.](http://www.gaggl.com/2011/12/installing-mysql-workbench-on-ubuntu-11-10/)

I choose to install using ppa launchpad so I can confirm that worked for me at an amd64 distro.

**EDIT**: Link replaced as suggested below by CodeReaper

Comment: The link is broken... :-/ So I am going to use this link instead  http://www.gaggl.com/2011/12/installing-mysql-workbench-on-ubuntu-11-10/

Answer (score 2):

In fact, mysql-workbench is available in the Ubuntu repositories (universe/database), so it should show up in Synaptic/Software-center/etc.

```
 aptitude search mysql-workbench
 aptitude show mysql-workbench
```

Comment: Reconfirm this in 12.04's repositories, this information you have stated is conflicting with other information I have seen.

Comment: Can you please tell me a little more detail?

Comment: mysql-workbench package is indeed available in the Ubuntu "universe" repo for 12.04:  `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe mysql-workbench i386 5.2.38+dfsg-3 [11.7 MB]`

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu (I have installed in Ubuntu 16)
run below command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

referred link: [mysql community website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html)

and below command also works:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you do a Google search?

The [first](http://setupguides.blogspot.ca/2012/04/install-mysql-workbench-on-ubuntu-1204.html) or [second](http://blog.brunobraga.net/mysql-workbench-on-ubuntu-1204-beta) search results for `ubuntu 12.04 mysql workbench` should do the trick.

*Please note: I am aware that LMGTFY-type answers aren't encouraged on this site; however I did not see the need to answer the question in detail if an easy-to-find blog post explained everything already.*

Comment: Good suggestion, but I am a little scared about installing external packages (packages from unknown sources).

Comment: Usually there's no problem. If you're nervous, however, try the second link. You'll see that it contains links to files on `packages.ubuntu.com`. This site is hosted by Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu. If a package is on that site, then there's every reason to believe that it's safe to install.

Comment: second blog link is definitely the answer

Comment: The post isn't available anymore in the second link. You should have copied the content in your answer ;(
Actually the same website has a post on installing MWB on Ubuntu 12 http://blog.brunobraga.net/mysql-workbench-on-ubuntu-12-10/