# How to automatically fetch missing dependencies when installing software from .deb?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm trying to install [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) on my Ubuntu box (11.04). The website has a Ubuntu .deb available for download (for 10.10 and 10.04 so I chose 10.10).

However,

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.34-1ubu1010-amd64.deb
```

yields:

```
(Reading database ... 194069 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql-workbench-gpl 5.2.34-1ubu1010 (using mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.34-1ubu1010-amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mysql-workbench-gpl ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-gpl:
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libctemplate0; however:
  Package libctemplate0 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libpython2.6 (>= 2.6); however:
  Package libpython2.6 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libzip1 (>= 0.8); however:
  Package libzip1 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on python-paramiko; however:
  Package python-paramiko is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on python-pysqlite2; however:
  Package python-pysqlite2 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-workbench-gpl (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.en_US.utf8.cache...
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-gpl
```

My question is, **is there a way to tell dpkg to automatically fetch missing dependencies**, or do I need to manually `apt-get install` missing packages like libctemplate0 and  libpython2.6?

(Or alternatively, is there some other way to get MySQL Workbench easily up & running?)

Comment: @Braiam: how can this question be a duplicate of a question posted three months later?

Comment: This question has better answers and is far more popular of the two, so indeed [the other one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79767/automatically-solve-dependencies-of-deb-packages-while-using-dpkg-i) should be marked as duplicate of this.

Comment: @Jonik Right now this question has 221,988 views and the question it's closed as a duplicate of has 241,929 views, so if this was once the more popular of the two, it isn't anymore. As for the quality of the answers, would it be sufficient for the answers here simply to be merged into the other question? Moderators can do that (if we ask them and they agree). The answers would appear on the other question (along with its answers) rather than this one. This question would still exist and still link to the other question and continue helping people find the answers. What do you think of this?

Comment: Oh, it's my question from 6 years ago. :) Honestly, I don't think it matters much. I'd just leave it as it is. Merging muddies the waters, as some of the answers inevitably become offtopic. If you *must* do something, then go ahead and do what seems wise.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can install a package and get dependencies from repositories with

```
sudo gdebi package.deb
```

If you already installed the package with missed dependencies, you can dowload and install dependencies automatically with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Also available is a graphical version `gdebi-gtk`, linked to `.deb` nautilus right click action "Open With GDebi Package Installer".

Comment: Thanks, `sudo gdebi mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.34-1ubu1010-amd64.deb` worked smoothly. Looks like gdebi is exactly the tool I needed.

Comment: nice one there,thanx ;-)

Comment: Note that double clicking on the deb file should work too. It will use gdebi on older Ubuntu versions and the Software Centre in newer.

Comment: To fall into the second case above: dpkg --force-depends -i some_deb_file.deb

Comment: Ouch! I installed `gdebi` on a clean server, it is HUGE. It really has tons of dependencies...

Comment: Install `gdebi` with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install gdebi`. It added only 35.7 MB of disk space and took just a handful of seconds on a recent Ubuntu 22.04.2 install.

Answer (score 36):

From the 1.1 branch onwards, `apt-get` supports installing local packages along with dependencies in the way of:

```
sudo apt-get install ./your-package.deb
```

Note the `./` in front of package file name, which is mandatory otherwise the name will be used as package name, not a file name.

Answer (score 30):

`dpkg` itself **is not capable of managing repositories**. A higher-level tool like `apt-get` is required to fetch anything from repositories. `dkpg` is only the **core tool** that installs/removes/configures packages, taking care of dependencies and other factors. `apt-get` and `aptitude` are tools that manage repositories, download data from them, and ***use*** `dkpg` to install/remove packages from them. This means that `apt-get` and `aptitude` can resolve dependencies and get required packages from repository, but `dpkg` cannot, because it knows **nothing** about repositories.

Comment: Good background information but not a useful answer.

Comment: Awesome. So where's the solution?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `apt-get -f install` to install all the packages `dpkg -i` complains about (but looking at your question you probably knew that ;) ).

`gdebi` might be a better alternative.

```
Description: Simple tool to install deb files
gdebi lets you install local deb packages resolving and installing its 
dependencies. apt does the same, but only for remote (http, ftp) located 
packages.
```

On a 3rd note... `gdebi` was replaced by the Ubuntu Software Center. If you install the .deb from within GDM (nautilus) USC will take over and try to install the `deb`. And that includes the dependencies. That is if you are not bound to command line ;)

Comment: Never thought of `apt-get -f install`, thanks! Looking for command solutions, quite aware of both `gdebi` and USC.

Comment: Oh wait, `gdebi` is command line tool. I'm sorry to ask this, but can you remove your answer? It seems this question was a duplicate, and I delete any duplicate question of mine. :) Comment on the question if you do.

Answer (score 6):

That particular library(`libctemplate0`) I downloaded it from

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/amd64/libctemplate0/download
```

The direct link `http://ubuntu.wikimedia.org/ubuntu//pool/universe/c/ctemplate/libctemplate0_0.96-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

The mySQL-workbench installation went smoothly after that.

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the package file and select "open with Ubuntu software center",  It will install everything for you.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, `dpkg` provides no mechanism for dependency resolving. It checks/warns for dependencies, but does not do any further action. You'll have to solve the problems on your own.

As the Debian wiki states [here](http://wiki.debian.org/dpkg):

> dpkg checks dependencies and will refuse to install a package whose dependencies aren't met, **but it won't help you find and install those dependencies. You need a higher-level tool (eg dselect or apt-get) for that**.

So I think that you'll have to use `apt-get` or `aptitude` in order to install the package you're interested in, as well as any dependencies involved.

Since this package is not in the 11.04 repositories, just run:

```
sudo apt-get install libctemplate0 libzip1 libpython2.6 python-pysqlite2 python-paramiko
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.34-1ubu1010-amd64.deb
```

and you should be ok.

Comment: Running 11.04 also, but I get "has no installation candidate" for most of the packages in your first apt-get. Am I missing something?