# Problem installing Google Earth .deb file

Tags: installation, deb, google-earth

I have been trying to install Google Earth on my netbook running 11.04. I have the .deb file in my directory `/home/andy/` but when I use terminal with the command `sudo dpkg -i /home/andy/googleearth_6.0.3.2197+0.6.0-1_i386.deb`,  I get the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing /home/andy/googleearth_6.0.3.2197+0.6.0-1_i386.deb 
(--install): cannot access archive: No such file or directory
```

Is this a typo on my part or is the sudo command accurate and it could be another issue? Also when I double-click this file, it automatically open the software centre application which is then frozen and I have to close it. Can a `.deb` be installed any other way?

Comment: Heve you written the filename correctly? You can get help from TAB key to complete correctly the filename. Are you sure the file is in your home and not, say, in your Downloads directory? Also see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58202/how-to-automatically-fetch-missing-dependencies-when-installing-software-from-de/58207#58207

Comment: The file is in the directory as mentioned above, not in the download and the file name is correct. I can add a screenshot if necessary but not sure how to upload one to this forum.

Comment: I would see the output of `ls -l /home/andy/googleearth_6.0.3.2197+0.6.0-1_i386.deb`

Comment: enzotib, I tried the command and it seemed to 'force' an install but the following message appeared as a package of bad quality:    Lintian check results for /home/andy/googleearth_6.0.3.2197+0.6.0-1_i386.deb:
E: googleearth: maintainer-name-missing <root@andy-N150P-N210P-N220P>

E: googleearth: maintainer-address-malformed <root@andy-N150P-N210P-N220P>

I'm not sure if the original .deb is corrupted or there is a conflict with my system.

Answer (score 2):

The error you receive is about the package not being found, or not being readable.
It should not be about a corrupted package.

As it has been already asked to you, please report output of:

```
ls -l /home/andy/googleearth_6.0.3.2197+0.6.0-1_i386.deb
```

You can also try the following command:

`dpkg --info /home/andy/googleearth_6.0.3.2197+0.6.0-1_i386.deb`

This should return some basic information about the package, and so it would do a couple of checks useful in your situation:

- the file exists and it's readable
- the file is a real .deb package and it is not corrupted

Comment: bitwelder, have installed the .deb from the above link and so have already deleted original .deb file with which I had the problems, but thanks for you input on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded Google earth 32bit from here:

http://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html

When Chromium finished downloading, I just clicked on it once and it installed no problem. I'm running it on a Dell Optiplex 755 micro tower with integrated Intel Q35 graphics so it's not the most powerful PC in the world but Google earth runs just fine.

Comment: User 23951, downloaded file from the link you supplied and opened it in software centre. I had to install two times but it did the job and now it is successfully loaded. Many thanks