# Automatically solve dependencies of deb packages while using dpkg -i

Tags: dpkg

Installing Deb packages on the command line, using `dpkg -i`, only installs the package in question and displays errors of unresolved dependencies (manually solved by `apt-get`ing the packages it complains about). How do I automatically resolve dependencies when installing standalone packages?