# lib64readline6 conflicts

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I've recently upgraded to a 64-bit machine (Kubuntu 12.04.02 AMD64) and in trying to assemble the list of things to compile some things I get conflicts. In trying to install `lib64readline6` or `lib64readline6-dev` I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib64readline6:i386 : Depends: lib64tinfo5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libc6-amd64:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
```

I variously also try to include `libc6-i386` (32 bit library for AMD64) as well as other combinations of things but I still get the conflicts.

Comment: see the accepted answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58202/how-to-automatically-fetch-missing-dependencies-when-installing-software-from-d