# How to install GNU Parallel in Ubuntu 12.04 with my firewall?

Tags: software-installation

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 in our production system. How do I install GNU Parallel in my system?  My system is behind a firewall so it will block any download from external connection.

Comment: do you mean behind a firewall?

Comment: Yeah.. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have physical access you could download the package parallel_20130922-1_all.deb from  https://packages.debian.org/sid/parallel and install like any other debian package. You may also need to locate and obtain the packages it depends on and install them first. Always Insure that you have recent backups and a recovery plan before making changes to a production system. Of course you probably already know that.

Full disclosure.  I have neither tried nor tested this. The answer is based on experience with installing other debian packages under ubuntu, nothing more

You can install with dpkg -i pkgname, if you have unresolved dependencies you may wish to check this thread

[How to automatically fetch missing dependencies when installing software from .deb?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58202/how-to-automatically-fetch-missing-dependencies-when-installing-software-from-d)

Comment: I can download on my desktop and then transfer it from my system to production system. But from this link, what I should download? https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/parallel/download

Comment: @Webby All those links are mirrors to the same package. Choose the site closest to you

Comment: Thanks. I have downloaded parallel, now I am not sure what next I should do?

Comment: @Webby updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to install GNU parallel version 20141022 on Ubuntu 12.04LTS? If I have used .

> /configure

, everything was ok, but when I have used

> make

I received error like : pod2pdf not found. using old sem.pdf etc...

Comment: That is just a warning: It simply means that if you have changed *.pod, then these changes will not be converted into *.pdf. And if you never changed *.pod the warning is safe to ignore.