# MySQL Workbench for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install MySQL workbench?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45115/how-to-install-mysql-workbench)

MySQL workbench is not available for 12.04, it is at the moment available upto 11.04 only.

I tried to install the Workbench 11.04 version on my Ubuntu 12.04, but no success.

(I just opened the deb package using Software centre, but the following error messages displayed)

[image]