# What components are needed for MySQL Workbench?

Tags: 12.04, mysql-workbench

I have read this AU Q&A titled: [MySQL Workbench for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147077/mysql-workbench-for-ubuntu-12-04-lts) and installed mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.43-1ubu1204-i386.deb. When setting up a connection to the MySQL running on localhost or remotely, I get this error:

```
Connecting to MySQL server localhost... 
Cannot start SSH tunnel manager
```

I'm not sure what else to install. BTW, with almost no effort MySQL navigator works just fine to the same systems.

My system is:

> Linux steamboy 3.2.0-31-generic-pae #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:39:45 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

and I grabbed the 32-bit workbench. I'm running 12.04 with all current updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to add one tunnel. Check [this link](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/manage-ssh-tunnels-with-gnome-ssh-tunnel-manager.html)
2. Reinstall the following packages:

   ```
   python (2.7.3-0ubuntu2)   
   python-all (2.7.3-0ubuntu2)   
   python-appindicator (0.4.92-0ubuntu1)   
   python-apport (2.0.1-0ubuntu10)   
   python-apt (0.8.3ubuntu7)   
   python-apt-common (0.8.3ubuntu7)   
   python-aptdaemon (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu2)   
   python-aptdaemon-gtk (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu2)   
   python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu2)   
   python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu2)   
   python-aptdaemon.pkcompat (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu2)   
   python-avahi (0.6.30-5ubuntu2)   
   python-beautifulsoup (3.2.0-2build1)   
   python-cairo (1.8.8-1ubuntu3)   
   python-crypto (2.4.1-1ubuntu0.1)     
   python-gnomekeyring (2.32.0+dfsg-1)   
   python-gnupginterface (0.3.2-9.1ubuntu3)   
   python-mysql.connector (0.3.2-1)   
   python-oauth (1.0.1-3build1)   
   python-openssl (0.12-1ubuntu2)   
   python-paramiko (1.7.7.1-2)   
   python-pycryptopp (0.5.29-1build1)
   ```